# Swift 3.0 retrieving int from Data

Tags: ios, swift3

Here is the code:

```
func match(_ match: GKMatch, didReceive data: Data, fromRemotePlayer player: GKPlayer){

    if(gameOver){
        return;
    }
    if(variables.background){
        match.disconnect()
    }

    if(!randReceived){
        levelLabel.text = "Match Against "+(match.players[0] ).displayName!
        self.addChild(levelLabel)

        randReceived=true
        var number: Int = 0
        number = data.withUnsafeBytes {
            (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> Int in
            return pointer.pointee
        }
    }
}
```

It gives an error saying "Value of type Data has no member 'withUnsafeBytes'". How do I fix this?

Comment: @staticVoidMan completely different question than that one

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any problem with your code. I tried the essential part in playground. Try to clean the project and build.

Comment: I’m very confused. I tried it in a different class also and it still didn’t work. Not quite sure what’s wrong.

Comment: weird. [this is what I tried in playground](https://gist.github.com/staticVoidMan/659d4c64c8e4ebf5e47f912de37007b6). Just put it somewhere in your class and see if the same error pops up.

Comment: @staticVoidMan another weird thing was that when I tried to create a Data object, it said something along the lines of "this type takes no arguments"

Comment: hm... have you defined your own `Data` type; as a class/struct/something?

Comment: @staticVoidMan I am actually stupid. That's probably it. I'm not at my computer right now but when I'll get back I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: @staticVoidMan if you want some rep post it as an answer and ill upvote and accept if it works

Comment: Well, there we go. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. I tried the essential part in the playground without any problem:

```
var test: Int = 1000
let data = Data(bytes: &test, count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)

var number: Int = 0
number = data.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) -> Int in
    return pointer.pointee
}
```

---

In your case, the error is:

> Value of type Data has no member 'withUnsafeBytes

Basically such an error would indicate that it can't find that particular function on the `Data` object.
You may have defined your own `Data` as a class/struct/something that has overridden the `Data` struct defined in `Foundation`.

---

Option-Click it and confirm it says:

> Declared in Foundation

[image: Foundation Data]

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, It would help you

```
extension Data {
    func copyBytes<T>(as _: T.Type) -> [T] {
        return withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<T>) in
            Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes, count: count / MemoryLayout<T>.stride))
        }
    }
}
```

Or

```
let size = MemoryLayout<Int16>.stride
let data = Data(bytes: [1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0]) // little endian for 16-bit values
let int16s = data.withUnsafeBytes { (bytes: UnsafePointer<Int16>) in
    Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes, count: data.count / size))
}
```